# C# Programmatically creating xyseries

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scichart

I am trying to create an `XyDataSeries` for every column of my `Datatable` programmatically to be used for charting (SciChart). I need to do this is because the amount of columns and names are unknown in advance.

For any given series the x value will always just be an incrementing integer from 0 and the y values are the column values.

I am importing excel data into the `Datatable` and then passing each column to a `Dictionary` as a `List` where the column header is the name of the `List` by the following;

```
dict = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToDictionary(c => c.ColumnName, c => dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r[c]).ToList());
```

Can i do something like the above where `Dictionary<string, XyDataSeries<double, double>>`?

Assuming i did know the amount of columns and their names, I could do something like this for every column/list;

Manually creating an `XyDataSeries` and iterating through a list to append the values. I then set the chartseries.DataSeries for the chart (defined in XAML) to the respective `XyDataSeries`.

```
var list = dict["ListName"];
XyDataSeries<double, double> xyseries;
xyseries = new XyDataSeries<double, double>() { SeriesName = "ListName" };
foreach (var i in list)
{
    double x = 1;
    var d = Convert.ToDouble(i);
    xyseries.Append(x++, d);
}
chartseries.DataSeries = xyseries;
```

I also have to declare the series in XAML - Can I get around this?

Having to do this over 600 times is far from ideal though and I am really desperate for an elegant solution for this.

Comment: you can iterate over Dictionary: `foreach(var keyValuePair in dict) { var list = keyValuePair.Value; ... }`

Comment: Hi, yeah i figured i could iterate over the dictionary, what really want to know is how can i create one `Dictionary<string, XyDataSeries<double, double>>` so that I can iterate over that to return the XyDataSeries? Rather than having to set them all manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can i do something like the above where `Dictionary<string, XyDataSeries<double, double>>`?

The `ToDictionary` method accepts a `Func<TSource, TElement>` as its second argument. So you could create and populate the `XyDataSeries<double, double>` in this one. Something like this:

```
dict = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .ToDictionary(c => c.ColumnName, c =>
    {
        var dataSeries = new XyDataSeries<double, double>();
        double x = 1.0;
        dataSeries.Append(dt.AsEnumerable().Select(_ => x++), dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => Convert.ToDouble(r[c])));
        return dataSeries;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and I get an exception basically saying it cant implicitly convert type List<> to Dictionary<>... The datatable is null until its data is imported through a click event, would a null value cause an issue here?

Comment: Where are you converting a List to a Dictionary...!?

Comment: Think i mis-understood the error; `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collection.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, SciChart.Charting.Model.DataSeries.XyDataSeries<double, double>>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, SciChart.Charting.Model.DataSeries.XyDataSeries<double, double>>'`

Comment: Thanks. The only strange thing is that the x value seems to change depending on how much data i pull in rather than always starting at 1 for each series. Any thoughts on this?